# Mongoose creates MongoDB object in database but returns empty object on server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an ExpressJS API connected to a MongoDB database that I'm interacting with through mongoose. The issue is that when calling the endpoint, the object is created in the database but not on the server and when calling `.save()` it always triggers an exception because it thinks that the Poll object is empty. Here is my model file:

```
//Poll.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Poll = new mongoose.model(
    "Poll",
    new mongoose.Schema({
        userId: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'userId is required']
        }, 
        title: {type: String},
        item: [{
            name: {type: String},
            votes: {type: Number}
        }],
        pollStatus: {type: Boolean},
        pollLength: {type: Number},
        createdBy: {type: String},
        totalVotes: {type: Number},
        hasVoted: [{
            required: false,
            userVoterId: {type: String, required: false}
        }],
    }, {timestamps: true})
);

module.exports = Poll;
```

Here is the section of the controller file that is causing the issues:

```
//poll.controller.js

try{
    const poll = Poll.create({
         userId: userId,
         title: title,
         item: item,
         pollLength: pollLength,
         createdBy: createdBy,
         pollStatus: true,
         createdAt: new Date(),
         totalVotes: 0,
    });
                
                
    poll.save((err, poll) => {
        if (err){
           return res.status(200).json({
              success: false,
                 error: err
           });
        }
        if (poll){
           return res.status(200).json({
              success: true,
              poll: poll,
              message: 'Poll created successfully'
           });
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
           success: true,
           message: 'Poll created successfully'
        });
    });
}catch(e){
   console.log('cant create poll');
   return res.status(200).json({
      success: false,
      err: e,
      message: 'Error creating poll'
   });
}
```

When trying to print the poll object on the server it is always empty. It also always enters the catch block that states `'Error creating poll'`. Because it still creates the object in the database it isn't the biggest issue but not being able to handle the response accordingly is definitely not ideal. Any help would be appreciated and the code can be found at [link](https://github.com/ckade15/easy-polls).

Comment: mongooses' `create` function is async. You have to `await` it to get the results. Otherwise it'll be empty when you call `save`. (and btw, as per the docs, `create` is a shortcut to `save`, so you don't even need to call that). see [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-create)

Comment: Thank you so much! Using `await` on the results fixed my  issue.